# Java MongoDB client as a singleton

Tags: java, object-oriented, singleton, mongodb

Is below code a valid Singleton design pattern for Mongodb in Java?

Please suggest any improvements.

```
public class Mongo extends MongoClient {

    private static Mongo mongoClient = null;
    private static MongoDatabase mogoDB = null;

    private Mongo(ServerAddress server, List<MongoCredential> mongoCredentialList) {
        super(server, mongoCredentialList);
    }

    public static Mongo getMongoClient() {
        return getMongoClient("userName", "password", "127.0.0.1", 27017, "SampleDB");
    }

    public static Mongo getMongoClient(String userName, String pwd, String ip, int port, String dbName) {

        if (mongoClient == null) {

            logger.debug("******* Trying to connect to Mongo Server *******");

            ServerAddress server = new ServerAddress(ip, port);
            List<MongoCredential> mongoCredentialList = new ArrayList();
            char[] password = pwd.toCharArray();
            mongoCredentialList.add(MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, dbName, password));

            mongoClient = new Mongo(server, mongoCredentialList);

            logger.debug("******* Connected to the Mongo server Successfully *******");
        } else {
            logger.debug("Already connected to Mongo server...");
        }
        return mongoClient;
    }

    public static MongoDatabase getMongoDatabase() {

        if (mogoDB == null) {    
            logger.debug("******* Trying to get Mongo DB - SampleDB - connection. *******");
            mogoDB = getMongoClient().getDatabase("SampleDB");
            logger.debug("******* Successfully Connected to - SampleDB - Mongo DB *******");
        }
        return mogoDB;

    }

    public static MongoDatabase getMongoDatabase(String dbName) {

        if (mogoDB == null) {    
            logger.debug("******* Trying to get Mongo DB - " + dbName + " - connection. *******");
            mogoDB = getMongoClient().getDatabase(dbName);
            logger.debug("******* Successfully Connected to - " + dbName + " - Mongo DB *******");
        }
        return mogoDB;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should [avoid the *Java Singelton Pattern*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) and pass around the (single) instance manually or use a DI-framwork taking care of the instance being a singelton!

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: No. Unless if your application only ever runs on 1 thread.

The easiest way to lazy initialise a singleton thread safe would be with a [holder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom). Example from wikipedia:

```
public class Something {
    private Something() {}

    private static class LazyHolder {
        static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();
    }

    public static Something getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This is thread safe because the java class loader ensures that the INSTANCE is initialised exactly once, when the LazyHolder class is used for the first time.

Since the database you initialise isn't known at compile time in this class you cannot use this pattern. What you can do is a pattern called [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking):

```
public final class Singleton {
    private static volatile Singleton instance = null;

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Important here are the `synchronized(...)` and `volatile` keywords.
The synchronised part makes sure only 1 thread can execute the construction code. And the `volatile` ensures that all threads always see all changes to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Typically yes, it is a good practice to make MongoClient a singleton.

As mentioned in the [MongoDB Java driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/getting-started/quick-start/):

> The MongoClient instance represents a pool of connections to the
> database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient even
> with multiple threads.

Comment: That suggests to me that you need one client instance _per database_ (which could be several instances in your unit tests, where you're using a different mock database for each test).

Comment: @TobySpeight I agree the term "database" is confusing, it actually mean database server or cluster. Note that you are requesting a (list) database object from the MongoClient.